# C# Get strings inside of parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I have the `List<string>` below:

```
"(TOP (S (ADVP (RB best)) (NP (NN hotel)) (. .)))"
"(TOP (S (NP (NNP Belmont) (NNP Copacabana)) (RB Palace) (. .)))"
"(TOP (FRAG (ADJP (JJ beautiful)) (NNS facilities) (. .)))"
"(TOP (NP (NP (NN time)) (PP (IN of) (VBG booking)) (. .)))"
"(TOP (NP (JJ excellent) (NNS rooms) (. .)))"
"(TOP (FRAG (NP (NN breakfast)) (NN option) (. .)))"
"(TOP (NP (NNP South) (NNP America) (. .)))"
"(TOP (FRAG (ADJP (JJ Amazing)) (NN staff) (. .)))"
"(ADJP (NN world) (JJ wide))"
```

Foreach string i need get a string is NN or NNS for example:

```
For:
"(TOP (S (ADVP (RB best)) (NP (NN hotel)) (. .)))"
Return:
hotel

For:
"(TOP (NP (JJ excellent) (NNS rooms) (. .)))"
Return:
rooms
```

If the sentence doesn't contains NN or NNS and contain NP i need return all words inside NP (), for example:

```
For:
"(TOP (S (NP (NNP Belmont) (NNP Copacabana)) (RB Palace) (. .)))"
Return:
Belmont Copocabana
```

I've started a method but it's with lots of If's. Does anyone know a better way to do this?

My code at moment:

Where item is the setence like ("(TOP (S (ADVP (RB best)) (NP (NN hotel)) (. .)))")

```
foreach (var item in wordsNouns)
                    {
                        var clearedText = item.Replace("(TOP ", "").Replace("(. .)))", "");

                        if (clearedText.Contains("(NP "))
                        {
                            var firstIndexNP = clearedText.IndexOf("(NP ");
                            var firstIndexCloseNP = clearedText.IndexOf("))");
                            var firstStep = clearedText.Substring(firstIndexNP, firstIndexCloseNP).Trim();

                            if (Regex.Matches(item, @"\(NP ").Count > 1)
                            {
                                var secondIndexCloseNP = clearedText.IndexOf("))", firstIndexCloseNP);
                                firstStep = clearedText.Substring(firstIndexNP, secondIndexCloseNP).Trim();
                            }
                        }
                        int NN = Regex.Matches(item, @"\(NN ").Count;
                        int NNS = Regex.Matches(item, @"\(NNS ").Count;
                        int NP = Regex.Matches(item, @"\(NP ").Count;
                    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? It seems like with something like this, it might be better to use recursion to solve this (possibly even by building a tree, since this basically *is* a serialization of a tree).

Comment: At now I just try it:

Comment: I've updated the post with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
var lines = new[]
{
    "(TOP (S (ADVP (RB best)) (NP (NN hotel)) (. .)))",
    "(TOP (S (NP (NNP Belmont) (NNP Copacabana)) (RB Palace) (. .)))",
    "(TOP (FRAG (ADJP (JJ beautiful)) (NNS facilities) (. .)))",
    "(TOP (NP (NP (NN time)) (PP (IN of) (VBG booking)) (. .)))",
    "(TOP (NP (JJ excellent) (NNS rooms) (. .)))",
    "(TOP (FRAG (NP (NN breakfast)) (NN option) (. .)))",
    "(TOP (NP (NNP South) (NNP America) (. .)))",
    "(TOP (FRAG (ADJP (JJ Amazing)) (NN staff) (. .)))",
    "(ADJP (NN world) (JJ wide))"
};

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(line, "(\\(((NN)|(NNS))\\s(?<text>[a-zA-Z]+)\\))|(\\(NP\\s(\\(NNP\\s(?<text>[a-zA-Z]+)\\)\\s?)*\\))");

    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        var text =  matches[0].Groups["text"]
                              .Captures.Cast<Capture>()
                              .Aggregate("", (str, capture) => str + capture.Value + " ")
                              .Trim();

        Console.WriteLine(line + " --> " + text);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(TOP (S (ADVP (RB best)) (NP (NN hotel)) (. .))) --> hotel
(TOP (S (NP (NNP Belmont) (NNP Copacabana)) (RB Palace) (. .))) --> Belmont Copacabana
(TOP (FRAG (ADJP (JJ beautiful)) (NNS facilities) (. .))) --> facilities
(TOP (NP (NP (NN time)) (PP (IN of) (VBG booking)) (. .))) --> time
(TOP (NP (JJ excellent) (NNS rooms) (. .))) --> rooms
(TOP (FRAG (NP (NN breakfast)) (NN option) (. .))) --> breakfast
(TOP (FRAG (ADJP (JJ Amazing)) (NN staff) (. .))) --> staff
(ADJP (NN world) (JJ wide)) --> world
```